# Show that ${{n}\choose{x}}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

> **Question:** Suppose $x $ is a non negative integer. Define ${{m}\choose {x}}=0$ if $x>m $. Let $\{p_n\}$ be sequence satisfying  $0 <p_n <1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} np_n=\lambda$. Show that $${{n}\choose {x}}p _n^x (1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Is this equivalent to the proof of Poisson Distribution formula ? I am asking this because in the statent ment of Poisson Distribution formula $np$ is constant but here when $n\to\infty $ $np\to $some constant$=\lambda $. Also in the Poisson Distribution Formula $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {{n}\choose{x}}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$ but we have to prove for any $n $ there is no limits. So is the proof for the problem and the proof of the Poisson distribution formula same ?

**Note:** There is no limit in the formula in the problem. We have to prove $${{n}\choose {x}}p _n^x (1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$ not $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {{n}\choose{x}}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Comment: Why do you say "but we have to prove for any $n $ there is no limits"?

Comment: There are no limits...someone added them

Comment: The claim does not hold when there is no limit involved. Note that the rhs does not depend on $n$ but the lhs does depend on $n$. Therefore only if the lhs would return the same value for every $n$ this claim would have a possibility to hold. You can however easily come up with a sequence $p_n$ for which this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\boxed{\text{Hint}}$

$$\binom{n}{x}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\frac{(np_n)^x}{n^x}\frac{(1-np_n/n)^n}{(1-p_n)^x}$$

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}np_n=\lambda$, we get $$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-np_n/n)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\lambda/n)^n=e^{-\lambda}}$$

$$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(np_n)^x=\lambda^x}$$ and try to show that $$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-x)!n^x}=1\\\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-p_n)^x=1}$$

Comment: There is no limit in the formula in the problem

Comment: We have to prove $${{n}\choose {x}}p _n^x (1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$ not $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {{n}\choose{x}}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}
$$

Comment: @SohamChatterjee Seriously? I thought that was just a misprint on your part. It's obvious the limit-free version of the statement is false for some finite $n$ if $p_n=\lambda/n$ for $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit you have written is the formal statement of the [Poisson limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem).

The version you saw before has a slightly less general assumption (it forces $np_n = \lambda$ for all $n$, rather than $np_n \to \lambda$). The proofs will be very similar, but you'll probably have to do something extra for the more general claim.

In both statements, there is a limit as $n \to \infty$; I am not sure what you mean by "we have to prove for any $n$ there is no limits."

Comment: Someone edited and added the limits..but in the problem there is no limit in the formula...here we have to prove the formula for any $n $

Comment: We have to prove $${{n}\choose {x}}p _n^x (1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$ not $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {{n}\choose{x}}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}
$$

Comment: @SohamChatterjee As others have pointed out, the omission of the limit is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $x$,$$\frac{\binom{n}{x}}{n^x/x!}=\prod_{i=0}^{x-1}(1-i/n)=\exp\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}\underbrace{\ln(1-i/n)}_{\sim-i/n}\approx\exp\frac{-x(x-1)}{2n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}1.$$As $n\to\infty$, $1-p_n\to1$ so$$\binom{n}{x}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}\sim\frac{\left(\frac{np_n}{1-p_n}\right)^x(1-p_n)^n}{x!}\sim\frac{\lambda^x e^{-np_n}}{x!}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}.$$

Comment: We have to prove $${{n}\choose {x}}p _n^x (1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$ not $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {{n}\choose{x}}p_n^x(1-p_n)^{n-x}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}
$$

Comment: @SohamChatterjee The limitless statement admits the counterexample $\lambda=1,\,p_n=1/n,\,n=10,\,x=0$, since $0.9^{10}\ne1/e$.